# android NFC isoDep setting disabling auto read response

Tags: android, nfc, smartcard-reader

Is there a way to disable android from sending auto read response to the cards like in java
  System.setProperty("sun.security.smartcardio.t0GetResponse", "false");
  System.setProperty("sun.security.smartcardio.t1GetResponse", "false");

Comment: Which Android device did you find that automatically handles GET RESPONSE processing? I tested this on a few devices and non of them did that...

Comment: Samsung generally